# Paperclip with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I have a app with a frontend app in AngularJS, sending JSON requests to my Rails backend app. I'm using Paperclip and Devise, and the spec for the `User` model changed in order to permit the uploading of an image.

Since I already have a `image` attribute, to store the url returned by Omniauth logins, I created a new attribute to my `User` model, with the command:

`rails g paperclip user stored_image`

And run the consequent migration.

My `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  has_attached_file :stored_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/noimg.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :stored_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And my registration controller, that I'm using to override some Devise limitations is the following

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # debugger
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end
end
```

My `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :json
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  after_filter :set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
  protect_from_forgery  #with: :null_session
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def handle_unverified_request
    forgery_protection_strategy.new(self).handle_unverified_request
  end

  def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
    cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
  end

  protected

  def verified_request?
    super || valid_authenticity_token?(session, request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'])
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:current_password ,:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :sex, :phone_number, :location, :birthday, :stored_image)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :sex, :phone_number, :location, :birthday, :stored_image ) }
    end
  end
```

It's important to clarify, that the user only uploads his image in an update action. So I when I debug in the `update_resource` action and inspect the `params` I see that the `stored_image` is not present, and therefore unable to store the image. Is my `application_controller.rb` correct to enable devise to accept image uploads?

Comment: So what's the issue here?

Comment: Some thing weird happened, submitted the question before it was completed and didn't realize that

Comment: Have you permitted `stored_image` in your strong params ?

Comment: argh, I forgot to put my `application_controller.rb` in the question, is where you config devise strong params right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem here was not no related with strong params. For some reason, I had to first parse the request as JSON, and then update the attributes, in this case, the `stored_image` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [THIS](http://www.peoplecancode.com/tutorials/adding-custom-fields-to-devise) article on how to add custom fields to Devise.

> This is because the way Rails 4 deals with "mass assignment." Due to security reasons we have to explicitly permit parameters inside each controller.

In your *app/controllers/application_controller.rb* explicitly permit your parameter - in you case `stored_image`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :stored_image) }
        end
end
```

Comment: I am already explicitly adding `stored_image` in strong params, check the updated question, that's already included in my `application_controller.rb`